# Connecting to Remote Desktop on Raspberry Pi after wifi has changed

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I am using VNC remote desktop on a raspberry pi 4 that is currently set up to run on my home WIFI network. This part works fine. The problem I have is trying to change the WIFI network on the pi and still be able to remote desktop connect to it. I already have the wifi credentials of the other network I am trying to remote connect to entered in the "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" file.

Does the connection rely on the local IP address of the computer VNC is running on? Would I need to make the IP address static? Please let me know if you've solved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot of detail missing from your question that will be needed in order for someone to answer it.  When you connect the Pi to the second network, are you still trying to access it from the same computer?  Are you also moving that computer to the new wifi network?  If the second network dynamically assigns a different address to the Pi (which is likely) then you will need to know that address in order to access it.  Using a static address would only work if both networks use the same address range in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this post because I figured it out. There is a two-step process to creating a remote cloud connection. First, log into the raspberry pi through the ip address in vnc viewer. Once connected, log into your realvnc account on the pi. This will create a cloud connection. Add the new wifi networks you plan on connecting to in the "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" file. Once the pi is connected to any of these new wifi networks you will be able to then remote connect back into the pi over the cloud connection.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the accepted answer